# Changed font-size on phone

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The company I work for wants me to develop their mobile website, I run into a few bugs, though. On my phone screen (Windows Phone (8.1), but also Android devices) the font looks much bigger than supposed to.

[image: First image, text looking much bigger than meant.]

[image: Second image, text also a lot bigger.]

[image: How it's meant to look]

The design is meant to look

I have added a meta viewport, but it did not change the font-size accordingly. Who can help me out on how to tackle this problem? Is there a common way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually occurs if you are using a fixed font size (px) instead of dynamic font size (em) you should look into converting the base font (default font size) to a pt then refer to it using ems

Comment: I have set a fixed font-size for the body, but after that I use em's, so I am not sure if I am doing this right?